# How to import the javascript generated by protoc?

Tags: javascript, meteor, protocol-buffers

I am new to protobuf.
I have installed npm google-protobuf.

Following is my .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.sixdee;
message Student{
        string name = 1;
        int32 id = 2;
}
```

And this is how i have generated the .js file

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. testproto.proto
```

i have pasted the resulting `testproto_pb.js` in my project.
I am not able to build a protobuf packet.
I have tried

```
var student = new Student();
student.setName("Ankith");
student.setId(24);
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Student is not defined`

I have referred [link](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/js). nothing seems to work for me.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: If you're using CommonJS-style imports then I think you would want to do something like this: var testproto_pb = require('./testproto_pb.js'); var student = new testproto_pb.Student(); ... Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with our code. It's hard to judge without the full source code.

I used protobufjs from npm as outlined here: http://webapplog.com/json-is-not-cool-anymore/

You need protobuf library on the front-end as well.